How should I implement Python code execution in bat
I tried using Python - c '''
...
'''
in the bat file to execute the code.
But in the first line break, there was an error of "SyntaxError: unterminated triple-quoted string literal (detected at line 1)"
How should I solve this problem
Code example:
echo end
python -c '''
print(1)
'''


yes I have modified my content, there is a line break before print (1)

@cherisezhang why did you expect triple single quotes to work in a batch file? Please share your actual batch file code, and explain what outcome you expected.

@Grismar I wanted to execute Python code in a bat file and found this execution method online, so I wrote a demo test, but it clearly failed

Perhaps you can explain more about why you needed this in the first place, but the easiest solution by far would be to put your Python code lines in a .py file and just run python script.py

What does echo end do? I can't reproduce the problem because I can't enter the bash. Also, forgive me for asking a dumb question but what's bash anyway? And what's echo and how are they related? Perhaps [edit] to add the commands before your code will help me understand better. I'm really bad at command-line scripting and stuff like that so forgive me in asking these questions, but can anyone please explain a bit? How did OP get to that point? I would like to know so I can reproduce the problem. Thanks!

python -c "print(1)"

As long as you have .py in your PATHEXT environment variable, you can execute Python scripts exactly like batch files.  That is, typing script will run script.py.  Thus, there is literally no reason to use trickery like that.

@TimRoberts, but this is not launching any scripts, it is running python command line, python -? states -c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list). Therefore in a windows batchfile python -c "print(1)"

@LukeL Happy that you're trying to learn a new skill, but the comments on a Stack Overflow question aren't the best place to do it. I'd recommend that you find a tutorial on the Batch Script language instead.

The question comes down to "here's something that cannot work, but you can probably see what I want, please suggest ways that do work", which is just soliciting opinions about ways to solve a simple problem - which is a good reason to close it.
